# How to find out when Oracle table statistics became stale?

Tags: oracle

`ALL_TAB_STATISTICS` has a column named `STALE_STATS`, but is there a way to determine the date when it became stale?

Comment: check LAST_ANALYZED column

Comment: No, there is not. But why would you need that information?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the view definition, you'll see that staleness isn't a column value stored in a table anywhere, but a formula calculated at query time:

```
  when ((m.inserts + m.deletes + m.updates) >
        to_number(decode(p.valchar, null, (select spc from stale_pc),
                         p.valchar)
                 )/100 * t.rowcnt
       )
  then 'YES'
  else  'NO'
```

It gets the modification data from `sys.mon_mods_v`, which tracks the # of rows inserted, deleted and updated since the last statistics gathering event. If the # of rows modified is more than a certain percent ("stale percent") then the segment is considered stale. So to know when that happened would mean knowing the modification statistics from the past. While there is a `timestamp` column, it only reflects the last time the segment was modified, which doesn't tell you how much the modification counters were incremented at that time, so it's not really usable.

I don't believe this data is retained historically in Oracle. You would need to capture `dba_tab_modifications` at regular intervals and create your own historical data to achieve this. But probably there isn't a pressing reason to do so.